# How to give object constraint to generics T in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How to give object constraint to generics?

I tried with below approach

```
const arr = <T extends Record<string, unknown>> (list: T[]) => {

}

arr<List>(list) //error at this line

// Type of list 
interface List{
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

Here I am getting type error as

```
type List[] is not assignable to Record<string, unknown>[]
```

I tried with `object` type instead of `Record`. But I got lint error as object
means nullish value.

Comment: `any` instead of `unknown`?

Comment: No explicit any, linting rule.

Comment: well, yeah, sure, but if you want an `AnyObject` type, its signature is `[key: string]: any`.

Comment: I need some explanation why we need `any` here instead `unknown`. Could you provide it in the answer?

Comment: There’s also `object`, unless you have another linting rule against that too

Comment: I am going with `any` and thinking to `off` that no explicit any rule. Here I want to know about why this error message is shown up. Here list is only checking extended type only. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Record<string, any>` instead of `Record<string, unknown>`. If we don't know what type it would be, then its better to put `any`.

```
type Any = any;

const arr = <T extends Record<string, Any>> (list: T[]) => {
}
```

Here , `Any` is different than `any`, the meaning of `Any` type is that it doesn't know about the type it will come and it is going to be fixed with correct type.